# Spring MVC - String Parameter with '-' resolved as '?'

Tags: json, spring-mvc, docker

I have implemented a api from which I wanted to run docker commands. Most commands worked fine, but when I tried to run the following command

```
    {  

  "command":"docker run -d -p 1506:1506 –p 2003:2003 --name=dradis dradis-licensed:v1"
}
```

on the server side the 2nd '-p' parameter was actually being converted to **'?p'**

Any clues why this would happen and any escape charaters I should be using?

Cheers
Kris